# Bootstrap multiselect to get values of optgroup and option

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-multiselect

As I have a select element optgroup with values also bonded with it. Here is a structure I have below.

```
<select id="example-dataprovider-optgroups" multiple="multiple">
<optgroup label="Lime No. 2" value="b3a2eff6-5351-4b0f-9861-0d47e136517d">
    <option value="90b4365b-9ddc-4c08-9e42-03662d73d923" label="Chimneys and Towers"></option>
    <option value="6a7d30d8-e500-476f-a2c6-7adfb47a3e00" label="Height Safety"></option>
    <option value="eb89ab4a-0431-4ed2-b6ba-a0c1bc91b0f0" label="Lightning Protection"></option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Lime No. 4" value="42da4f3e-1944-4f42-a5b7-350871cbffea">
    <option value="90b4365b-9ddc-4c08-9e42-03662d73d923" label="Chimneys and Towers"></option>
    <option value="6a7d30d8-e500-476f-a2c6-7adfb47a3e00" label="Height Safety"></option>
    <option value="eb89ab4a-0431-4ed2-b6ba-a0c1bc91b0f0" label="Lightning Protection"></option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Lime No. 1" value="46ec4dec-e669-4829-b99a-5ac64340eb84">
    <option value="90b4365b-9ddc-4c08-9e42-03662d73d923" label="Chimneys and Towers"></option>
    <option value="6a7d30d8-e500-476f-a2c6-7adfb47a3e00" label="Height Safety" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="eb89ab4a-0431-4ed2-b6ba-a0c1bc91b0f0" label="Lightning Protection"></option>
</optgroup>     
</select>
```

Now as I'm using bootstrap multiselect like this below.

```
$('#example-dataprovider-optgroups').multiselect({
                enableFiltering: false,
                enableClickableOptGroups: true,
                includeSelectAllOption: true,
});
```

With **optgroup** as clickable. Now I require values of **optgroup** as well as within its **option** values as well. I tried using the method below.

```
$("#example-dataprovider-optgroups").each(function (index, item) {
                console.log(index);
                console.log(item);
                $(item).find('li').each(function (index1, item2) {
                    console.log(item2);
                });
                //console.log(item.find("multiselect-item multiselect-group active"));
                //console.log(item.find("option:selected"));
            })
```

How can I achieve to get values from both..?

**Update 1:**

```
$("#example-dataprovider-optgroups").find("optgroup").each(function (index, item) {
      console.log(index);
      console.log(item);
      console.log($(item).find(":selected")); // i don't get selected value from optgroup
   })
```

Comment: In your code example, all options under each option group are the same, but in reality, would each option have an unique GUID as value? If yes, then it's possible to locate the option group. Otherwise you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.multiselect-container` which is created by the plugin to get all values which is selected . So, whenever you select any options it is added under `ul > li` with class `active` so using `.active` get selected option value and to get option group use `$(this).prevAll(".multiselect-group:first").text()` .

***Demo Code***(Your provided html was having duplicate values i have added dummy values there ) :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example-dataprovider-optgroups').multiselect({
    enableFiltering: false,
    enableClickableOptGroups: true,
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
  });
  $("button").click(function() {
    console.clear()
    //loop through ul > li which has class active (selected)
    $(".multiselect-container").find("li.active:not(.multiselect-group)").each(function(index, item) {
      //get li value and get group name
      console.log("Selected -- " + $(this).text() +"Values - "+$(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").val()+ " From Group -" + $(this).prevAll(".multiselect-group:first").text()+"Values - "+$(this).prevAll(".multiselect-group:first").find("input[type=checkbox]").val());

    })
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />


<select id="example-dataprovider-optgroups" multiple="multiple">
  <optgroup label="Lime No. 2" value="b3a2eff6-5351-4b0f-9861-0d47e136517d">
    <option value="90b4365b-9ddc-4c08-9e42-03662d73d923" label="Chimneys and Towers"></option>
    <option value="6a7d30d8-e500-476f-a2c6-7adfb47a3e00" label="Height Safety"></option>
    <option value="eb89ab4a-0431-4ed2-b6ba-a0c1bc91b0f0" label="Lightning Protection"></option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Lime No. 4" value="42da4f3e-1944-4f42-a5b7-350871cbffea">
    <option value="90b4365b-9ddc-4c08-9e42-03662d73d922" label="Chimneys and Towers4"></option>
    <option value="6a7d30d8-e500-476f-a2c6-7adfb47a3e03" label="Height Safety4"></option>
    <option value="eb89ab4a-0431-4ed2-b6ba-a0c1bc91b0f3" label="Lightning Protection4"></option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Lime No. 1" value="46ec4dec-e669-4829-b99a-5ac64340eb84">
    <option value="90b4365b-9ddc-4c08-9e42-03662d73d9231" label="Chimneys and Towers1"></option>
    <option value="6a7d30d8-e500-476f-a2c6-7adfb47a3e001" label="Height Safety1"></option>
    <option value="eb89ab4a-0431-4ed2-b6ba-a0c1bc91b0f01" label="Lightning Protection1"></option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
<button> Click me !</button>
```

Comment: How do i get values from both thanks for the text.. i used $(this).attr("val") result "" and this as well $(this).val() result 0 for options and for optgroup $(this).prevAll(".multiselect-group:first").attr("val") used this

Comment: Updated answer have a look .